# TinyMCE 5.1.3 Rich text editor is not loading in IE 11

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using tinyMCE 5.1.3 (Angular6 ) (none cloud version ) within the application version, like placing tinymce files, themes under asset folder of angular scaffolding.

In my angular.json I have the below configuration::

```
"assets" :[
    {
    "glob": "/*",
    "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins",
    "output": "/skins/"
    },
    {
    "glob": "/",
    "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes",
    "output": "/themes/"
    },
    {
    "glob": "**/",
    "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins",
    "output": "/plugins/"
    }
    ]
    "scripts": [ "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" ]
```

```
package.json
"tinymce": "^5.1.3",
```

I have similar configuration (atleast 100%) as below plnkr (component and html wise )

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/E5Yzk9KT9nSWlPU6i1ZK?p=preview&preview
```

Everything works in chrome latest version, however the *rich text editor* is not getting visible in `IE11`. One thing I could see on IE is that it says `theme.js` not found `( 404 ) error`, I am not sure if this is really behind editor not being visible on `IE11`.

Also what could i see is that the url for theme.js in IE different then URL of chrome. in Chrome it points to dist folder of server, however in IE it just points to scaffolding of the project.

in IE

```
http://myserver/gateway/myapp//themes/silver/theme.js
```

in Chrome: ( this I can hit in sepearte window with file I can see )

```
http://myserver/gateway/myapp//themes/silver/static/items/my-app-ang/dist/themes/silver/theme.js
```

but if someone has similar issue could help me in this ?

Comment: Guys, if any one can help me on this, is this webpack-ing issue ? configuration issue ?

Comment: I am wondering why we need <div class="hidden"> as plnkr I attched, if I remove it shows two editors.

Comment: Guys, anyone can help plesase

Comment: There any one ?